# unused import in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

[image]

I created a dart file while importing in main dart file it'showing the error unused import try to import the directive.how to import the problem?

Comment: That is an unused import warning not an error, so please remove that line and you won't see that warning

Comment: did you how to import the task.dart file because task adding function i written there.

Comment: Press alt+enter for any needful import if it shows an error, otherwise you don't need to import anything

Comment: it's changed into " import 'package:my_app/task.dart';".

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is very smart IDE.
In your code you have imported `task.dart` file but that file is not in use. (You are not using any resource of that class.)
So if you remove that class from your file you will have a batter and clean code, also at compile time that file will be not imported in your code.
Which is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

that's not an error that a warning .
you can delete your `import "task.dart"` to remove the warning